# I am trying to retrieve every third letter of the string above. I am having trouble determining how to begin

Tags: python, string

[image]

I tried to use this code: print(os.path.basename(path)[::3])

However, it is giving me this in return "Ph_in" which is not the answer I am looking for. I am not sure why it is only doing the file name from the path and not the whole strin.

Comment: Nothing from `os.path` is even slightly appropriate for use with a URL string; they're for file pathnames only.

Comment: 1) use proper tags, missed the most important one: `python` 2) [Do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use plain text instead. 3) looks like homeworks

Comment: _I am not sure why it is only doing the file name from the path_ Because that's what `basename()` does...

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I tried to use this code: print(os.path.basename(path)[::3])
>
>
>
> However, it is giving me this in return "Ph_in" which is not the answer ..."*

The *[os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)* method will return the last part of the path, in this case *"Python_I.ipynb"*.

Instead, just use *path*.

```py
path = 'http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Python_I.ipynb'
print(path[::3])
```

Output

```
hp/cht8/tosyoIpb
```

For the final requirement, you can use the the following syntax to reverse a string.

```py
path[::-1]
```

```
bnypi.I_nohtyP/skoobeton/8888:tsohlacol//:ptth
```